# port redirect not working for https apache2

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache2, httpd.conf, bitnami

I am trying to configure apache2 on aws lightsail instance. the instance was default setup for aws wordpress + aws linux. I have a node.js server running on port 5000 on this instance.

the apache server is in `/opt/bitnami/apache2`.

First I tried to redirect port to 5000 for non-http requests ad it worked well.

here is the .conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://example:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://example:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

then I configured ssl certificate with bitnami bncert-tool. I turned force https redirect on while configuring ssl.

then i configured `example-https.conf` like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/example.com.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/example.com.key"

  # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://example.com:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

but this time it's not working. requests are being redirected to https and resposes is from wordpress, not my node.js server.

these `conf` files are in `/var/www` and i have included them in `httpd.conf` using

```
Include "/var/www/*.conf"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can deploy a custom Node application on top of the Bitnami solution by following these steps:

- Run the following commands to create the directories:

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/myapp
  sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/myapp/conf
  sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/myapp/htdocs
  ```
- Create and edit the */opt/bitnami/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf* file and add the line below to it:

  ```
  Include "/opt/bitnami/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf"
  ```
- Create and edit the */opt/bitnami/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf* file and add the content below to it. This is the main configuration file for your application, so modify it further depending on your application's requirements.

  ```
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
  ```

  > NOTE: 3000 is the default port for the Express server. If you have customized your application to use a different port, change it here as well.
- Once you have created the files and directories above, add the following line to the end of the main Apache configuration file at */opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf*, as shown below:

  ```
  Include "<%= variable :app_directory, :platform %>/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
  ```
- Restart the Apache server:

  ```
  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
  ```

You can now use the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool to generate Let's Encrypt certificates and access your application using http and https.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by replacing `<VirtualHost *:80>` with `<VirtualHost *:443>` on the `example-https.conf` file

still waiting for a better answer, thanks.